# how to move scene position in cocos2d on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5, widescreen

I have made a game on cocos2d-iphone for iPhone 4, to make it compatible on iPhone 5 wide screen I want to move cocos2d's scene a little bit on right on the iPhone 5 screen. I am trying to move scene by 50 points but after few seconds it gets back to its original position.

```
scene.position = CGPointMake(50, 0);
```

I have also set Default-568h@2x.png image in the cocos2d project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really dont need to change the position of the scene. Just change the position of the layer that is added to your scene